# Plotting lm curve does not show using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

As per ex18q1 in "R for Data Science" I am trying to find the best model for the data:

```
sim1a <- tibble(
  x = rep(1:10, each = 3),
  y = x * 1.5 + 6 + rt(length(x), df = 2)
)
```

I've applied linear model and am trying to plot the results on a graph using ggplot:

```
sim1a_mod <- lm(x ~ y, data = sim1a)

ggplot(sim1a, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, colour= "gray") +
  geom_abline(intercept = coef(sim1a_mod)[[1]], slope = coef(sim1a_mod)[[2]], colour = "red")
```

`coef(sim1a_mod)[[1]]` prints -1.14403

`coef(sim1a_mod)[[2]]` prints 0.4384473

I create the plot with the data points, but the model is not showing.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can cheat and just use `+ geom_smooth(method = "lm")` instead of `geom_abline`

Comment: @Phil Thanks, I noticed that when googling, and that's a great solution.  For my comprehension though, and considering I'm pretty new to r I'd like to understand where my mistake is, and why this is not working

Comment: The issue was with your model. Try it with `sim1a_mod <- lm(y ~ x, data = sim1a)`

Comment: @Phil I see...  Thanks for that.  Credit where credit's due if you put that in an answer you get the points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nomenclature for typing formulas for model functions like `lm()`, `glm()`, `lmer()` etc. in R is always `DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + ... + IVn` where `DV` is your dependent variable and `IVn` is your list of independent variables. We typically chart the dependent variable on the y-axis and the independent variable on the x-axis, so in your case you'll need to change your `sim1a_mod` model to `lm(y ~ x, data = sim1a)`.

In your original code, because you were running a different model, your line was being charted, but it was outside of your view. If you attempt to chart again with your original model with the following code you will then see your regression line:

```
ggplot(sim1a, aes(x, y)) +
geom_point(size = 2, colour= "gray") +
geom_abline(intercept = coef(sim1a_mod)[[1]], slope = coef(sim1a_mod)[[2]], colour = "red") + 
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-30, 30)) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-30, 30))
```

[image]